# How can I avoid duplicating work on a collectFirst call?

Tags: scala

I have something like this:

```
   val yyy = aListOfObjects.collectFirst{
     case x if(x.calc("input").isDefined) => x.calc("input").get
   }
```

I have some list of things.  Each thing has a method, calc, that does work to bring back an optional result, if the calculation was successful or not.

I want to go thru the list of things and bring back the calculated value of the first one that is successful, or None if none of them work.

The snip above does this, but... you'll see I call x.calc() twice.  Assuming the call to calc is non-trivial, how can I avoid the double call?  (I also don't want to pre-call calc() on all things since I only care about the first one that works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that Streams are lazy in scala:

```
aListOfObjects
  .toStream
  .flatMap { _.calc("input") }
  .headOption
```

Or define your own extractor:

```
object Calc {
   def unapply(x: TypeOfX) = x.calc("input")
}
```

Now, you can write: `listOfObject.collectFirst { case Calc(x) => x }`

Comment: Interesting.  Let me try the former idea.  The latter may be an issue because I don't actually know "input" until runtime, so in a perfect world I'd be able to pass it in to unapply as a 2nd parameter, but I'm not sure that's valid.  (I just tried the 2nd method and it was happy with an implicit parameter on unapply to pass in "input".)